# How to draw a diagonal line in a container with dynamic size?

Tags: flutter, dart, widget

I have a container with a text widget as child. The size of the container will change based on the length of the text. I'm using constraints property of the container to limit max and min height/width.

To draw a diagonal line across the container, I'm using a CustomPainter wrapped in a container, which has the same constraints as that of the first container.

There is a Stack widget with the two containers, so that the diagonal line appears on top of the first container.

The pseudo code is as below:

```
    Stack(
     children: [
      Container1(
       constraints: _getConstraints()
       child: Text()
      ),
      Container2(
       constraints: _getConstraints()
       child: CustomPaint(painter: LinePainter())
      ),
     ]
    )
```

The issue is, `Container1` size depends on the length of the text, and `Container2` dosen't know that size. Because of that, the diagonal line draws with the `minHeight` and `minWidth` of the constraints.

How can I make `Container2` the same size as that of `Container1`? Or is there any other solution to draw the diagonal line correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to simply use your painter as a `foregroundPainter` like so:

```dart
CustomPaint(
  // foregroundPainter makes it draw on top of its child
  foregroundPainter: LinePainter(),
  child: Container1(
    constraints: _getConstraints(),
    child: Text(),
  ),
),
```

See also the official docs: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/CustomPaint-class.html